# How to keep on refreshing access_token so that the user is always signed in using oauth 2.0?

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, webserver

I have a react web application. There is an option to upload files from google drive. Once I sign in to google drive using google oauth 2.0 drive, I always want to be logged in to google drive. I have kept the refresh_token, access_token and expirationdate generated after login to drive in the database. The accesstoken expiry is 1 hour but I want to keep on refreshing indefinitely. I thought of creating a scheduler which keeps on refreshing the access_token but I am not sure how to do it because google is the one doing the refreshing. Is there a way to do this or any approach?

Comment: You can use the refresh token to request a new access token after the token expires, and idealy store the refresh token safely on the server

Comment: @Azzy I am trying that actually. But I am not sure how to send the request to Google oauth 2.0. Google has to send back the tokens right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Assuming that you are using implicit (client-side) OAuth 2.0, this grant type doesn't support refresh tokens. Instead, users should re-authorize when the access token expires.

That's because this kind of authorization flow:

> is designed for applications that access APIs only while the user is present at the application.

If you want to refresh an expired access token without prompting the user for permission, you should look into explicit (server-side) OAuth 2.0 (see [Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)):

> Server-side web applications, installed applications, and devices all obtain refresh tokens during the authorization process. Refresh tokens are not typically used in client-side (JavaScript) web applications.

#### Reference:

- [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)
- [Using the token model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the solution looking at the links shared